# XPath select element if other not exist

Tags: xpath

In some case we need to select `input[@class="some"]` element, but only if `div[@class="other"]` is not exist.
Both elements doesn't have common parent, except `body`, of course.

As soon as results of our environment focused on XPath we need only XPath solution.

UPD: if element exists nothing should be returned

Comment: So nothing should be returned in case `div[@class="other"]` exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try (not tested):

```
 input[@class="some"][not(//div[@class="other"])]
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks. We've decided use `and` instead of `][` for better readability but that's only about preferences. :)
`input[@class="some" and not(//div[@class="other"])]`